# How can I fix a "Sorry, you don't have access to this application" error when accessing app from link in email?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have an App Maker app that sends a notification email to a user when they have to take action on an item. The email includes a link into the app to access the item they need to take action on directly. For whatever reason, when they click on the email in the link, users are getting a "Sorry, you don't have access to this application" error.

- The URL generated in the email is correct, and exactly matches the URL you'd be at if you navigated to the same page/record from within the app.
- It looks like there's some kind of link resolution going on when you click on the email link -- there's a brief period when the URL in the address bar is of the form `https://www.google.com/url?q=https://script.google.com/a/xxxxx/macros/s/<correct script ID>/exec?evalId%3D823%23EditEvaluation&source=gmail&ust=<number>&usg=<string>`
- For almost all users, the link resolves to a URL in the form of `https://script.googleusercontent.com/a/macros/xxxxx/echo?user_content_key=<string>&lib=MxCG-Sk-HF4ilQO-Kv7w6fINeS3Mb45sS#EditEvaluation`, which then goes to a page that just has the "Sorry, you don't have access to this application" message.
- If I copy and paste the full correct URL (`https://www.google.com/url?q=https://script.google.com/a/xxxxx/macros/s/<correct script ID>/exec?evalId%3D823%23EditEvaluation`) into a new tab, it goes to the same error.
- The only time this error doesn't come up is when I'm logged in as the Admin user -- I can click on an email link or copy and paste the link into a new tab, and it loads just fine.

Here's what I've checked:

- In the deployment settings, the app runs under the user's account, and application access is not restricted.
- Access to the data models involved, as well as to all associated relations, is set to Everyone.
- Security for the page involved is set to Everyone.
- There are no permission-related bindings for visible or enabled anywhere on the target page.

Can anyone else see something I'm overlooking?